# how to delete account information

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

please let me know how to delete my account information from Magento online shopping website

Comment: Please add screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unless you create this function or you delete the customer from backend.

If you need a simple code to make it via PHP look at the following:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer
  ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
  ->loadByEmail($customerEmail)
  ->delete();
```